# how can i do multithreading in php

Tags: php, multithreading, curl

i am trying to rewrite my code to support multithreading ,it is a simple code but i can't figure out how to do it,basically what it do is

1. request the first webpage with curl --> to get a unique id
2. use the unique id to request another page --> to get a session
3. use the session to request another page --->sleep() then do it again

now this is what a single thread do,but i want to create a lot of threads in the same time

what i did is ,create 3 sperate files

the first one create 10 sessions and save them in a txt file with other parameters (session1|unique_id1|paramter1|anotherparameter1)

the second file contain this code

```
$sessions = file('sessions.txt');
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
foreach($sessions as $kk => $session) {
  if (!empty($session)) {

    $oExec = $WshShell - > Run("php requests.php $kk", 0, false);
  }

}
```

it open the txt file,and foreach line it open the requests file with the line number in argv

and in the third file,it take the line number ,and open  the sessions file ,retreive the paramater of the session and send requests with that session

so this is how i did my multithreading,but i feel like i wrote a php code with rocks 
now i want to rewrite it without having to open 10 sperate php process

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php - PThreads is an extension that adds threading to PHP. I personally just fork processes.

Comment: thanks for the answers,can you at least help me multi threading after i get the sessions, i mean i want to open all the sessions at once using curl
,i couldn't understand how curl_multi work :/

Comment: First, you need to install the pthreads extension. It is pointless to write code for pthreads if you don't have the extension installed. The link I provided shows you how to install it and how to create threads.

Answer (score -1):

There really isn't a native way to do threading in PHP.  The approach you took works, but I would approach it differently.  It's possible to fork processes in PHP.  This I've done and works well.

One approach is to use some messaging system like RabbitMQ and distribute the work that way.  Basically an Actor or Pub-sub model.

Another approach that might work well for you would be "pthreads".  http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php

I've not tried this method myself so I cannot give you details as to how well it does or doesn't work.

Hope this helps!